# Why is $||v||$ defined as $\sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$ and not just $\langle v, v \rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In inner product spaces, you can create an induced norm $||v||$ from the inner product by defining

$$||v|| = \langle v, v \rangle^\frac{1}{2}$$

But often (in proofs and whatnot) it's nicer to consider $||v||^2$. Why don't we define the induced norm as $||v|| = \langle v, v \rangle$?

Some reasons I could think of are:

1) Historically, this gives the straight-line metric for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

2) We are in some sense "double-counting" $v$ when we take $\langle v, v \rangle$, so we need to take the square root to "undo" it.

Comment: I think most people would expect that if $v=2w$, then $\parallel v\parallel=2\parallel w\parallel$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The triangle inequality fails if we tried defining the norm as $\langle v,v\rangle$. For instance, we would have, where $d(u,v)=||u-v||$, the distance function, on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$ for simplicity:
$$d(0,1)=1$$
$$d(1,2)=1$$
$$d(0,2)=4>d(0,1)+d(1,2).$$

Comment: Well that pretty much sinks it.